# Where am I missing a { or } in this small section of Android code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax-error

I seem to be having a problem with a syntax error within Eclipse while doing one of the tutorials from the Android for Dummies book. It's probably something simple, but I keep looking at the code and it seems right to me.. Here's a screenshot. Ah, I can't post images as I'm a new user. Here are the jpg links instead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DWzj.jpg

I can't figure out why Eclipse is giving me those three lines as an error. When I hover over it, it says that I'm missing a } or maybe I have too many, but I think I've accounted for all of them! When I remove those four lines starting with the second @Override, everything parse out correctly. Here it is without those lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcSHI.jpg

Comment: Remove the @Override and report if the error persists

Comment: Did you import ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a clever typo, but if you look very closely.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListItem 1, ...
```

has it's first parameter as a `ListItem`, but it has a variable name as the numeral `1`, not the letter `l`.  Since a variable name isn't allowed to start with a digit, the parameter list is not valid, so the method declaration is not valid, and hence the block under it is not properly opened.

It's obvious you meant the letter `l` as it is used within the block.

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks so much, this fixes the problem and the code executes properly. I must pay closer attention!

Answer (score 1):

You are using 1 as a variable name in this method

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView 1, View v, int position, long id){}
```

I think this is the cause of ur error. Check it